# enable to redirect particular intent in dialogflow cx

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to redirect by the given entity name of symptoms but still, it only redirects to one Intent page. if I type a full question i.e. added in phrases then only it redirects intermittent

I want to know how to redirect if I give only the symptom name then it should redirect to a particular intent and ask added parameter questions.